# How do I make a class stored in a 2d-array "aware" of their position in it?

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, matrix

I think the title says it all... but for completeness sake here is the full problem.

## The Problem

So, I have a 2-column array (a matrix, or "grid") in Visual Basic/C#/Anything.net comprised of `Cell` instances declared as `Public Matrix(,) As Cell`.

A `Cell` is roughly this:

```
Class Cell

    Public Value as integer
    Public Height as integer
    Public Tags as Dictionary

    Sub New(Optional v As CellType = CellType.Void)
        value = v
        type = v
    End Sub

    Function GetPos() as Point
        *need arcane necromancy here*
    End Sub

End Class
```

The question is simple, but I know the answer may not: can I get the `Cell`'s position without passing it in the constructor?

Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve (always given `Public Matrix(,) As Cell`):

```
Dim x,y as integer
Dim apple as Cell = GetARandomAppleFrom(Matrix)
x=apple.GetArrayPos.x
y=apple.GetArrayPos.y
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("An Apple is in {0}, {1}",x,y)
```

## A side question about the need of this question

At the moment I am using the following snippet of code to initialize all of the cells to a zero-value because using `Matrix.Initialize()` failed miserably leaving every element set to nothing.

If the methods description says it calls the default constructor, then *why did it fail?*

Although I doubt my initialization is correct from a coding/efficiency perspective, as I think that a double loop isn't that great...

```
 For x = 0 To Me.zWidth
     For y = 0 To Me.zHeight
         Matrix.SetValue(New Cell(CellTypes.Void), x, y)
     Next
 Next
```

I am sticking to it for now. Hence here is a

## Possible Solution

This implies that I could pass the indices to a Position field at initialization time - through the constructor - like this...

```
 For x = 0 To Me.zWidth
     For y = 0 To Me.zHeight
         Matrix.SetValue(New Cell(CellTypes.Void,x,y), x, y)
     Next
 Next
```

**But, since a `Cell` could change position or be overwritten, I would like its position to be dynamically determined.**

*However, if nothing better comes in the radar I will definitely use this approach and then update the value as per position changes,*

## Addendums

Some info that may - or not - be useful:

- The Matrix size is less or equal to (512,512)
- This is going to become a terrain data-map generator for an isometric (so no 3d, but I already have an height variable in cells) game with fairly small maps, with support to superficial features like mountains, river(s),

Comment: You only have two choices: (1) Pass the location to the Cell constructor (as you already mentioned and rejected) or (2) calculate the location on demand by searching for the cell in the container (an O(N) operation)

Comment: My question for you is, why is `GetPos` a method of `Cell` at all? Do you have a good reason for it, or is it just because it came naturally to you? Because in my experience, these questions are actually rather tricky and getting them things "right" sometimes involves making counterintuitive choices. In this case, I don't think a cell should know about its own position at all. How did you get a reference to the cell in the first place? However you did, it was probably not a great idea -- instead of storing a direct reference to the cell, you should be going through the matrix.

Comment: I am prototyping a terrain data-map generator for a game with fairly small maps, with support to superficial features like mountains,  river(s),

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just cut down your random picker to just return the x,y value found and use that to retrive your cell? Something like this:

```
Dim pt as Point
pt = GetRandomPosition()
Dim apple as Cell = Matrix(pt.X,pt.Y)
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("An Apple is in {0}, {1}",pt.X,pt.Y)
```

Comment: I want to have the `Cell` provide it on itself, as this is for a simulation in which I will also query the `Cell`'s position without knowing it previously. Random picking is to test the position retrieving system. :P

Answer (score 0):

It really is a question of modelling. I personally would prefer if cells knew about their position since it seems to be important to them, but for one you appear to dislike this approach, and for two, when updating positions this has to be done (by a helper method) in two realms at once - in the affected cells and in the grid, which can be problematic. Thus, something else:

How about stepping away from a simple 2D array towards building your own type like a somewhat smarter array which not only keeps the grid of cells as a simple 2D array, but also takes record of each `Cell` with their coordinates -- a dictionary which maps each contained `Cell` to a pair of ints representing the `x` and `y`. Let's call that smart array `SmartArray`. It would need methods for moving cells around, which update the map and the grid atomically (which is OK because all the changes are within the `SmartArray` "realm"). Then you can ask the `SmartArray` instance "Where on the grid is Cell `c`?" and you'll have an answer in `O(1)`. That'd be a tradeoff towards speed over memory footprint. Each `Cell` must, however, know about their containing `SmartArray` so it knows who to ask.

You can also leave out the map and keep the query methods, but make them traverse the grid each time a question is asked. The answer will be the same, lookups will take `O(n^2)`, but moving cells will be easier because you only have to update one structure. That'll turn around the tradeoff towards one favoring memory footprint over speed, and it is essentially the Double Loop you mentioned in the q.

Answer (score 0):

First off to initialize N elements you must call your initializer N times, no efficiency problem there.

To answer your question: Your item shouldn't care about its position. The position of an item in a collection is not a problem of the item itself and can lead to headaches very quickly if you move your item or change the collection.
What if your collection changes from a 2d matrix to a 3d one? You have to rewrite code and add a Z variable (and that just a quick example).

I'd try to structure my code/solution completely in another way.

By the way, a item can locate itself inside a collection by looking for a reference to itself. (Adapt code to your matrix as needed)

```
GetPosition( Array source)
{
    foreach(var element in source)
       Object.ReferenceEquals(this,element)
}
```

Performance are bad since you loop the collection but it may fit your needs

Comment: I didn't know we could do a `for each` on multi-index arrays... cool! What do you mean by "another way"?

Comment: If you delve in what you are trying to achieve we may suggest you the correct pattern to follow. It seems like your trying to find a trick to correct a  structural problem.